# SUM rows FROM a table only if one row have some match criteria with the rest of the rows

Tags: mysql

Sorry if the title is a little bit odd, but I am struggling even with explaining myself on this.

I am trying to create a soccer stats database. Right now I have a 'boxscore' table like this:

```
id_boxscore  id_player  id_team  goals  fouls
-----------  ---------  -------  -----  -----
1            1          1        1      3
1            2          1        3      5
1            3          2        2      8
2            4          5        0      6
2            4          5        0      6
3            2          1        5      9
3            3          1        11     4
```

So, for some advance data calculations, I need to know the accumulated totals from the team from games where the player participated. The good query should give me something like this if, for example, I am selecting accumulated stats from id_player = 1:

```
id_player  accGoals   accFouls
---------  ---------  --------
1          4          8
```

Right now my query is looking like this:

```
SELECT SUM(b.goals) FROM boxscore as b, (SELECT b.id_boxscore from boxscore as b 
WHERE b.id_player = 1) AS c WHERE b.id_boxscore=c.id_boxscore
```

But is giving me the accumulated stats from games where the player with id 1 has played (both from his team and from the opponent):

```
id_player  accGoals   accFouls
---------  ---------  --------
1          6          22
```

Any ideas? I am sure this is really simple but I am in a dead-end right now.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this close to what you expect?

```
SELECT a.id_player, SUM(b.goals) as accGoals, SUM(b.fouls) as accFouls
FROM boxscore as a
JOIN boxscore as b
    USING(id_team, id_boxscore)
WHERE a.id_player = 1
GROUP BY a.id_player
;
```

I.e. sum all goals, fouls from boxscore, where id_team and id_boxscore is the same as player 1

Comment: Yes! That works. Thank you very much, I have to start paying attention to the JOIN clause. I usually use INNER JOINs and there are many possibilities in other expressions.

Comment: `JOIN` is just a shorter form of `INNER JOIN`. Similar is `LEFT JOIN` a shorter form of `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. Both the shorter and the more verbose is standard SQL. Furthermore, `USING (id_team, id_boxscore)` is the same but shorter than `ON a.id_team = b.id_team AND a.id_boxscore = b.id_boxscore`. `USING` is also standard SQL

Answer (score 0):

One solution is this

```
SELECT 
    MIN(`id_player`) id_player,SUM(`goals`),SUM(`fouls`)
FROm
    boxscore
WHERE `id_team` = (SELECT `id_team` FROM boxscore WHERE `id_player` = 1 LIMIT 1)
GROUP BY `id_boxscore`
HAVING id_player = 1
```

REsult is

> ```
> id_player | SUM(`goals`) | SUM(`fouls`)
> --------: | -----------: | -----------:
>         1 |            4 |            8
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c06cf2f2969e7d919688d6abd037679e)*